# Showing a Set is Path Connected

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $X$ such that $X = [0,1] \times \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \{q\} \times [0,1] $

I know that from definition, a set is path-connected if $\forall x,y \in X$, $\exists$ a continuous map $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=x \text{ and } \gamma(1)=y$. If I could get a hint on how to approach this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}\{q\}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

Comment: Do you have an idea on what the path should be?

@spinosarus123 Perhaps because the implied topologies on the resulting spaces would then be different.

Comment: you have a comb of vertical pegs all connected by the base of the comb i.e. $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ (horizontal segment).

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I believe this would look like a comb with dense pegs emerging from each rational point on [0,1] all with height 1.  I believe that the path connecting any two points would involve traveling down the bristle and moving to the rational point and moving back up the bristle.

Comment: Yes, this is it, note that a shorter path exists if two points are on the same bristle though, but it does not matter if the path overlaps with itself in this case, it's still working well. Also you have to consider the end points not being on a bristle but on the horizontal segment (this is trivial though, but have to consider the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a path from $x$ to $y$ in a set $A$, and also one from $y$ to $z$, show that there is also a path in $A$ from $x$ to $z$.

Using that show that if $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is a union of path connected sets $A_i$ with the additional property that for some fixed index $j \in I$ we have $A_j \cap A_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$, then $A$ is path-connected.

The latter applies to your problem quite directly.

Comment: Maybe I have a wrong picture in my mind (or my approach is too naive as I have not yet taken topology courses) but if I try to envision a specific map $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$, $\gamma(t)=(a,b,c)\in X$ then $t$ can also attain irrational values. So if for example $t=e^{-10}$, how do we make sure that second coordinate remains in the set $\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}\{q\} $? How does this match with your answer?

Comment: @Philipp in general you’ll combine 3 paths. Two that are vertical and one horizontal.

Comment: But at some point in this process we have to vary the second variable. Then it could happen that it attains an irrational value because $t\in[0,1]$. How do we exclude this?

Comment: @Philipp you don’t need to.

Comment: Hmm I thought this violates the definition of path-connectedness? Maybe you can construct an example of such a path function $\gamma$?

Comment: @Philipp do you understand thoroughly how to combine paths?

Comment: I would simply construct such a $\gamma$ by traversing along each of the three axes separately while fixing the other two variables. So the result would be a piece-wise function.

Comment: @Philipp yes and you’d only have an irrational first coordinate on the horizontal path ($x$-axis). So I don’t see any issues.

Comment: Let's consider the two points $(0,\frac{1}{3},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2},0)$. Both are elements of $X$. When constructing $\gamma$ at some point, you end up with $\gamma(t)=(0,h(t),0)$. If $h$ attains irrational vaules then $\gamma(t)\notin X$. How do you avoid this?

Comment: @Philipp they’re not points of $X$. $X\subset \Bbb R^2$ !

Comment: How do you know that $X\in\mathbb{R}^2$? Does the cartesian product $\times$ always take precedence over the union $\cup$?

Comment: @Philipp here yes